# Define a type in a generic Class from a string in C#

Tags: c#, generics

**Is it possible to defines the type of a Generic Class using a string variable ?** I mean:

```cs
string myType = "System.string"
MyClass<myType> customClass = new MyClass<myType>();
```

I found some kind of examples but none of them works.

Many thanks in advance.

**NOTE: Normally, those types are going to be numbers: float, int, double, ... I'm getting the type from a database to make generic and abstract the code.**

I'm using this example: [Is it possible to serialize a list of System.Object objects using protocol buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905411/is-it-possible-to-serialize-a-list-of-system-object-objects-using-protocol-buffe/38914841)

Then, my problem is with the type, I won't know which one is going to be, so, using this other example (@devNull): [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

I don't know how to tell to use the constructor with the argument instead of the empty one.

Comment: It's possible with reflection, but the real question here is why you want to do it? This is usually a sign of a code smell.

Comment: To serialize the information of the database in a protobuffer, i need to know the type: double, int, ... In my backend, this information is store in the database with the value of the data. Why am I using this is not relevant

Comment: What examples did you find that didn't work? What about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/266115/5803406)?

Comment: you can run `MakeGenericType(typeArgument)` method to make generic type with argument. Argument type can be loaded  from the string value. [There is example how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/266282/940182) (you have that link in the question).

Comment: Finally that answer solves my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate types dynamically using [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamically-loading-and-using-types). That said, if you have control over both the serialisation and the deserialisation of objects, I would recommend using a NuGet package like [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/), which has ready-made functionality for [serialising](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) and [deserialising](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) your objects.

**Edit:** I just realised that you are only reading simple types from your database. In such a case, simple reflection will do. Examples:

```
var mySingle = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Single", false, true));
var myInt = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Int32", false, true));
var myDouble = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Double", false, true));
var myString = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.String", false, true), "some value".ToCharArray());
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using that NuGet package, but for another reason

Comment: .Dump() gives me this error: 'object' doesn't contain a definition for 'Dump' .... `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Single", false, true)).Dump();`

Comment: your samples (and answer) are for non generic classes. However OP asks about generic classes creation

Comment: @JoseteManu forget about `.Dump()` I accidentally left it in there because I was trying out my code in LINQPad. I have amended my answer.

Comment: @oleksa it's a bit confusing: he says generic class but then he says it's going to be in a `string` variable and he lists `float`, `int`, and `double` as examples. I have given an example for some simple types; for all more complex cases of classes, I have advised the use of the `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet package.

Answer (score -1):

There are always many ways to skin a cat. A simple way to handle a small set of types, which would seem to be what you want for using protocol buffers. A small set of if tests would probably be fine

```cs
object x = ...;

if (x is int i)
    ...
else if (x is decimal d)
    ...
```

Comment: This actually answers the opposite question. The OP is asking for a way to *deserialise* a `string` while your answer is about *serialising* an object into a `string`.

Comment: The OP has a string that contains the type information. The point still stands that it may be useful to check for specific values and deal with them .